# Sending continuous data over HTTP with Go

Tags: json, web-services, http, reactjs, go

I am currently working on a web service in Go that essentially takes a request and sends back JSON, rather typical. However, this particular JSON takes 10+ seconds to actually complete and return. Because I am also making a website that depends on the JSON, and the JSON contents are subject to change, I implemented a route that quickly generates and returns (potentially updated or new) names as placeholders that would get replaced later by real values that correspond to the names. The whole idea behind that is the website would connect to the service, get back JSON almost immediately to populate a table, then wait until the actual data to fill in came back from the service.

This is where I encounter an issue, potentially because I am newish to Go and don't understand its vast libraries completely. The previous method that I used to send JSON back through the HTTP requests was ResponseWriter.Write(theJSON). However, Write() terminates the response, so the website would have to continually ping the service which could now and will be disastrous in the future

So, I am seeking some industry knowledge into my issue. Can HTTP connections be continuous like that, where data is sent piecewise through the same http request? Is that even a computationally or security smart feature, or are there better ways to do what I am proposing? Finally, does Go even support a feature like that, and how would I asynchronously handle it for performance optimization?

For the record, my website is using React.js.

Comment: I think you might have better luck with WebSockets

Comment: As @AmmarBandukwala mentioned, [websockets](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket) is the way to go.

Comment: You could also consider HTTP/2 which is similar to websockets. All browsers do not implement it but most do today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use https websockets to achieve this effect rather than a long persisting tcp.con or even in addition to this. see the golang.org/x/net/websocket package from the go developers or the excellent http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket from gorilla web toolkit for use details. You might use padding and smaller subunits to allow interruption and restart of submission // or a kind of diff protocol to rewrite previously submitted JSON. i found websocket pretty stable even with small connection breakdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Go does have a keep alive ability net.TCPConn's SetKeepAlive

```
kaConn, _ := tcpkeepalive.EnableKeepAlive(conn)
kaConn.SetKeepAliveIdle(30*time.Second)
kaConn.SetKeepAliveCount(4)
kaConn.SetKeepAliveInterval(5*time.Second)
```

Code from [felixqe](http://felixge.de/2014/08/26/tcp-keepalive-with-golang.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use restapi as webservice and can sent data as a json.SO you can continously sent data over a communication channel.